# Anet A6 install bed leveling sensor

Tags: anet-a6

After lots of hassle, I finally made the printer work.

I also got myself one bed leveling sensor from eBay, [LJ18A3-8-Z/BX 3D Printer Inductive Sensor Bed Auto Level +Plug For Anet A8 A2 A6](https://www.ebay.com/itm/LJ18A3-8-Z-BX-3D-Printer-Inductive-Sensor-Bed-Auto-Level-Plug-For-Anet-A8-A2-A6/322718359043?hash=item4b23835e03:g:H14AAOSwicJZr8ro).

I'm not sure how to setup it. Should I print some holders for it first? Where are they?

Should I somehow update the firmware?

Comment: could you kindly google the phrase `Anet a6 install bed leveling sensor` and your problem will be solved :)

Comment: @profesor79 the point of this website is to help people and constantly telling them to go Google how to do it is not helping.  The traffic for this site should be coming from search engines because this site should be housing the answers to their questions.

Comment: @tjb1 thank you for the comment, AFAIK OP needs to demonstrate that there was a try to solve problem on OP own.

Comment: @profesor79 -  whilst you _are_ correct, could you kindly take a look at the answers to [Post Closing Issues](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/post-closing-issues). We are having a bit of a problem with [new] user retention, and we would like to address that. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two or three things:

1. Print a holder or bracket for the probe, if your probe did not come with one, and looking at the eBay item listing, it doesn't appear to include a bracket. There are a number of designs out there, take a look at thingiverse, for example:

   - [Installing the BLtouch on Anet A6](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2424360) - This one includes a PDF guide.
   - [Anet A6 Autolevel Sensor Support 18mm](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2030075)
2. Change the firmware - <strike>SkyNet 3D</strike>, Marlin is a good choice, or Anet's own
3. You *may* need to change the Z-stops

There is a step by step guide here, [Autolevel for the A8 Anet 3D Printer](https://3dprint.wiki/reprap/anet/a8/improvement/autobedleveling). It is for the A8 but most, if not all, of the steps will apply to the A6

Comment: Please note that Skynet3D, which was a fork from Marlin Firmware, has been merged into Marlin for quite some time now.